# Rails + Ransack: Sorting first by association.name = 'string', then everything else alphabetically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have books that has_many book_versions (paperback, hardcover, sixpack).

On the initial load of the index page, it loads this query:

```
@search = Book.includes(:book_versions).search(params[:q])
```

When someone tries to sort, I currently have this query:

```
@search = Book.includes(:book_versions).where( :book_versions => { :name => params[:book_version_name ] } ).search(params[:q])
```

The problem with this is that if `params[:book_version_name] = 'paperback'` it only sends back book_versions that have book_versions.name = 'paperback'. This means none of the other results show. Instead, I want it to:

1. first show the book_versions with name = 'paperback'
2. show all the book_versions with name != 'paperback'

How would I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you always want all of the books all of the time, so stick with your first query and then do your grouping in ruby?

```
@result = Book.includes(:book_versions).search(params[:q])
@book_version_name = params[:book_version_name]

# in memory filtering of the result
@primary = @result.select { |x| x.book_version.name == @book_version_name }
@secondary = @result.select { |x| x.book_version.name != @book_version_name }
```

see ruby select (not the rails database method) http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

```
# the above could probably be written this way as well
@primary = @result.select { |x| x.book_version.name == @book_version_name }
@secondary = @result - @primary
```